# Registering multiple web sites as subfolders in the same azure app service

Tags: domain-name-system, security, azure, cname-record

I want to create multiple web sites to be hosted in the same App service (something like cms). So, I will have in my app multiple web sites in different locations:

https://app_service/web/client1

https://app_service/web/client2

https://app_service/web/client3

...

I need to map different domains to each of those, such as www.client1.com point to the first location, etc.

How this can be achieved ?

In addition, everything need to be covered by secure connection, so I also wonder can I use just one IP certificate ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do it this way since a single App Service plan can support hundreds of Web Apps (depending on the plan size)?

Comment: This is the way how our app (cms) architecture is setup currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in Azure using tools like [Azure Front Door](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/frontdoor/) or [Application Gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) (I would recommend Front Door). This will allow you to configure your required URL's at the front end, and map those to path based rules at the back end.

Comment: Thanks, this techology looks promising. The one catch here is that I want to hold multiple static web sites on the same app service / blog storage, with different subdomains. Would it be possible to configure it to work like that ?

Comment: Front Door can send traffic to any back-end you like, including app service. So long as you can configure a URL for it to reach it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use CNAMEs to point your clients to the right service, for example 'cms.client1.com CNAME supercmsservice.com' You of course need to configure the webserver at `supercmsservice.com` to listen for requests for `cms.client1.com`

As for the SSL certificate, you'll need to add the names of the services ('cms.client1.com' in my example) as Subject Alternative Names in your certificate when you request it. Some SSL certificate vendors have different pricing for Multi-SAN certificates, so look into that before buying, as it makes it a lot cheaper compared to some other vendors that charge you by the SAN regardless if you request 10 separate certificates or 1 with 10 SANs.

If you're using Let's Encrypt, it's just a matter of adding more domains to the request.

Comment: How to configure servre to list from cms.client1.com ? And regarding certificate, isn't it possible to use SSL IP certificates ?

Comment: SSL IP certificates are a bit of a curveball to begin with, they are very rare and most providers don't even offer them. Also in this case they won't be possible to get, since one of the requirements is that you own the IP block to begin with, which you don't if you're hosting it in the cloud. See this for more info: https://www.geocerts.com/support/ip-address-in-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0):

We solved it using Azure Storage with Azure CDN Profile Endpoints.

The CDN Profile Endpoint forwards to Azure Storage, and we map the domain on it.